# Seasonality from ACF

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autocorrelation, seasonality, acf-pacf

I'm trying to determine whether there is seasonality in some data or not.

When I apply the ACF the data doesn't seem to be correlated but, with a 1st order diff, there might be with a lag of 7.
[image]

Since I need to forecast 36 more values should I consider this value or since there isn't seasonality use only the trend?

@edit
[image]
Added PACF

Comment: The variable is not stationary, and with exponential-ish growth at the start, differencing is not going to 'fix' that. Are these values some kind of count?

Comment: To inspect seasonality, use PACF in addition to ACF.

Comment: @Glen_b Its a time/value series (I use it to understand the topic, there isn't a real meaning for the data), I am trying to forecast the next 36 values just by fitting a normal distribution. For the forecast I need to check the seasonality so that, if there is, I sum it (since it's additive) to the trend prediction.

Comment: @RichardHardy I included the PACF, I know it represents the effect of the nth lag on the series but how do I interpret it in regard to seasonality?

Comment: Seasonality means there will be statistical dependence between $x_t$ and $x_{t-h}$ where $h$ is the length of the seasonal period. PACF reveals exactly this relationship as far as it is linear.

Comment: @RichardHardy So in this case which values represents the seasonal effect? From the ACF I see the first 6 values being correlated, which is confirmed by the 1st order ACF indicating a seasonal effect on 7. But the PACF indicates values as 5,8,9,22,26,27,29,31,32...

Comment: Yes, the patterns in your dataset do not seem to be what you would typically expect for seasonal data.

Comment: @RichardHardy Ok got it, Thanks!